# getting error while executing a select query which has case statement and join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting below error while executing a select query which has case statement and join.

**Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'..**

```
SELECT pb.Id,
         pb.Name,
            CASE 
            pb.Firstname
            WHEN (pb.lastName IS NULL OR pb.lastName = 'No') THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE pb.Firstname END,              
               pb.Email,
                   CASE 
                   pb.MiddleName
                   WHEN (pb.Code = 1 OR pb.Code IS NULL) THEN 'Yes' 
                   ELSE pb.MiddleName END AS MiddleName
FROM Table1 a
JOIN
  Table2 pb
ON
  Table1.Id = Table2.Id
```

Can anyone suggest what's the issue with this query?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the two forms of case.  The form you want -- searched `case` -- does not have a column after `case`:

```
        (CASE WHEN pb.lastName IS NULL OR pb.lastName = 'No' THEN 'Yes'
              ELSE pb.Firstname
         END) as Firstname,              
        pb.Email,
        (CASE WHEN pb.Code = 1 OR pb.Code IS NULL THEN 'Yes' 
              ELSE pb.MiddleName
         END) AS MiddleName
```

I am guessing that you want the first `CASE` expression to have the alias `FirstName`.